# Google apps scripts : get the URL of the spreadsheet and send it by mail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a button in my spreadsheet: I want it to send the URL of the spreadsheet when I click on it, but unsuccessfully right now.

**Here is my code:**

```js
function mail() {

var destID = '1kVhuTwVr80AScne9ijtlWs9YlDf5YkixIFVVbPjoX5E';
var recipient = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var sprURL = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
Logger.log(sprURL.getUrl());

GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, 'SUBJECT OF THE MAIL', 'The Spreadsheet sits at the following URL: ' + Logger.log(sprURL.getUrl()))

}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: run it from the debugger and see.

Comment: It doesn't display any error :/ Still, I receive a mail, but without any URL in it

Answer (score 1):

the error is that you are pasing logger.log(url) when you build the subject string. just pass sprURL.getUrl()

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't pay attention to that.